# how to solve $\frac{df}{dx}$ derivative against $dy$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If I take  derivative of  $\frac{df}{dx}$  against ${dy}$, will it be $\frac{d^2f}{dxdy}$. I am a little confused.
So to solve this we will look for those values which have variable $y$ in them in $\frac{df}{dx}$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of @BaronVT is nice. But if the function is $y=f(x)$ and you want to differentiate w.r.t. $y$ here it is 
$$\frac{d}{dy}[\frac{df}{dx}]=\frac{d}{\color{red}{dx}}[\frac{df}{dx}]\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\frac{dx}{dy}\\=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\frac{1}{f'}$$

Comment: why dx^2,won't it be just dx in denominator.

Comment: I edited it one more step @Rishi

Comment: now I get it. thanks

Comment: note that if the function contains 2 independent variables you have to use $\partial$ instead of $d$

Comment: how to type it,sorry new on Stackoverflow!

Comment: \partial between two $ signs, for the color \color{red}{...} do you accept it

Comment: Thank very much, I meant do you accept my explanation for the Latex writing or you need more

Comment: lol..For Latex ,if possible provide link to page where I can learn it myself.If get stuck again on something,will ask again.Many thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome any time. There  many ways [here](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/latex-type/latex-math-symbols/) and on this web right click on any symbol then choose latex

Comment: @Rishi you might also find this helpful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @BaronVT Thanks I was indeed looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly correct.

For instance if $f(x,y) = y^2 + y^4 \cos x + x^3$, then

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 + y^4 (-\sin x) + 3x^2 = -y^4 \sin x + 3x^2
$$

and so
$$
\frac{\partial^2  f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = (-4y^3) \sin x + 0 = -4y^3 \sin x
$$

Comment: A little correction,while calculating df/dx=0+y^4 instead of 0+y,although you have computed it correctly.while doing df/dx ,we are making y's part 0 ,because in this case it's considerd as constant(right?).But sometime we write derivative of y^2 against dx as y.dy/dx ,is that the case when y is a function of x i.e f(x)=y?

Comment: ok, yeah, sorry about that mistake. And yes, for the second step, we treat $y$ as a constant. And also yes, the situation you're describing is when $y$ is **implicitly** as function of $x$ (i.e. this is "implicit differentiation" which is a different topic)